# RadioButton's Or CheckBox in the AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-checkbox

How to use multiple `RadioButtons` or `CheckBoxes` in the `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Try this code....

```
    final CharSequence[] gender = {"Male","Female"};
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(uploadphoto.this);
    alert.setTitle("Select Gender");
    alert.setSingleChoiceItems(gender,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            if(gender[which]=="Male")
            {
                gen="1";
            }
            else if (gender[which]=="Female")
            {
                gen="2";
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```